# How to refer to foreign key linked table

Tags: python, django

I have two models:

```
class Incident(models.Model):
    iid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)

class Source(models.Model):

    sid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    incident = models.ForeignKey('Incident', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    url = models.TextField(validators=[URLValidator()])
```

I want to display every source linked to an incident, but this doesn't work:

```
{% for source in incident.source.all %} 
    {{ source.url }}
{% if not forloop.last %},
{% endif %}{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3):

Default reverse name for foreign key is `<modelname>_set`. So try this:

```
{% for source in incident.source_set.all %}
```

You can change reverse name using [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) option:

```
incident = models.ForeignKey('Incident', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='sources')
```

In this case incident's `sources` attribute will give you sources objects:

```
{% for source in incident.sources.all %}
```